# How to Avoid Assignment of Private Members in Constructor

Tags: c#

I often find myself doing this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }        
    private int x;

    ...
}
```

Every time I add a new private member variable for configuration, I need to add it to the constructor's parameter list, to the constructor body, and to the class as a member. Is there a good programming pattern for avoiding the extra typing?

Comment: Don't think so, no, and unfortunately due to the fact that the changes are in 3 different places it's not conducive to using code snippets, macros, add ins, etc.

Comment: This is one of my favorite features of Resharper.  I add a new parameter to the contructor, press Alt-Enter, enter, and it initializes a new field for the that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, If you instantiate a class with a bunch of private members that you have to pass into the constructor, you're doing something problematic already.

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(x, y, z, 7, 'c', someOtherClass)
```

If appropriate, you can encapsulate related fields into a struct or a different class like so

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Coordinates coords)
    {
        this.coords = coords;
    }
    private Coordinates coords;

}

public struct Coordinates
{
     public int X{get; set;}
     public int Y{get; set;}
     public int z{get; set;}
}
```

and then you can instanciate it with

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(new Coordinates() { X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3 });
```

---

Without a particular implementation, It's kinda hard to determine the optimal solution, but if you don't actually have to set the fields from outside your class, you can do something like

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }        
    private int x = 2;

    ...
}
```

or

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.x = 2;
    }        
    private int x;

    ...
}
```

Comment: 1) This doesn't actually answer the question 2) This is often not possible.  Clearly if you know the value at compile time you'll hard code it; but it's *very* common to need to accept it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for proposing passing a struct with configuration parameters. I like this syntax better. However, this is not all that helpful because on the inside you have more typing every time you want to access the members of that configuration struct. Result is more typing at the end of the day.

Comment: @ChrisMerck  "more typing" per-se is not the problem you should be worrying about.  What you actually should be worrying about is when you have to make the same change in multiple places(sometime you might forget one), and you also have to worry about being able to read your own code(or even someone else reading it) a month from now.

Answer (score 0):

I find that I can abuse inheritance to accomplish my goal. I set up a "Loader" subclass that has the sole purpose in life of plugging in the dependencies of the base class. Then we can work with the base class and forget about the loader.

Then again, this has the horrible side-effect of preventing use of these protected member variables in the base constructor -- we need to use a .Start() function or something like that instead. So, this is a pretty bad solution, although saving some keystrokes.

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected int param1;
    protected int param2;

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param1 + param2);
    }
}


public class MyClassLoader : MyClass
{
    public MyClassLoader()
    {
        param1 = 1;
        param2 = 2;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MyClass myObj = new MyClassLoader();
        myObj.DoStuff();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```